# AngularJS: How does the controllers communicated each other?

Tags: angularjs

http://jsbin.com/lakujiya/4/edit

Please help me,I think this way is right,but $scope in difference controller can't pass  Variables as I expected.I have no idea because i am fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `$rootScope.$broadcast` here http://jsbin.com/caravezi/1/edit,

```
  angular.module('myApp',[]).
    controller('SomeController', function($scope, $rootScope){
       $scope.title = 'have a try.';      

       $scope.clicked=function(){
         $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent', $scope.title);
       }
    }).
    controller('otherController', function($scope, $rootScope){
       $scope.$on('someEvent', function(e,title){
          $scope.title = title;       
       });
    })
```

`$emit` -- dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.
`$broadcast` -- dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes,

Comment: See I have added all the code here have a look in the jsBin, I have changed it little.

Comment: if correct. I can see two 'have a try',but i see one.

Comment: yeah I see your point , I think the second controller is not registered listener when first controller is broadcast the message.

Comment: see if you add some event and do it like above it works. and remember in the `$on` event handler the first parameter is the `event` second one is the data.

Comment: Thank you.but I still confused by the listener,I'll try to understand it.